# Use INFORMATION_SCHEMA get list of all datatypes in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes, information-schema

I know there are lists of the datatypes that MySQL supports all over the internet, but is there a way I can use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** to programmatically list them in real-time in my application?

I'm currently using the *GetSchema* method, but I'd rather use an SQL statement:

```
Connection.GetSchema("DataTypes"); //I don't want to use this, because you can't filter the columns it returns
```

How can I use **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** to list **ALL** the datatypes in a MySQL database, and not just types used by a certain table?

If there were a table called **INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATATYPES**, I could write a statement like this:

```
SELECT TYPE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.DATATYPES
```

But such a table does not exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to programmatically find them all. The typical discovery mechanism is a [SHOW](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show.html) command or the [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html).

Data types don't get added very often. Probably best just to use a [static list](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/data-types.html) sorry.

Answer (score 1):

is possible using the table `COLUMNS`

```
select DATA_TYPE from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

or

```
select DISTINCT(DATA_TYPE) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
```

Comment: This only returns types that are currently being used in the database. I ran your query on my database, and the result did not include the 'JSON' datatype, but it is still a valid MySQL datatype.